# Class not changing on scroll in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, scroll, dom-events

Following is my `handleScroll` function in which I am trying to add `red` class if it scroll down to a certain limit else apply `blue`. However this is only going inside the `else` statement and also `console.log(e.target.scrollTop);` its consoling as `undefined`. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**Code -**

```
handleScroll(e) {
    console.log(e.target.scrollTop);
    if (window.screenX > 100) {
      this.setState({
        navBckgroundColor: `red`
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        navBckgroundColor: `blue`
      });
    }
  }
```

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-feynman-m6hp1

Comment: any luck on getting this to work? :)

Comment: @ChristopherNgo ahh sorry..my system got crashed..upvoted

Comment: darn I hope you were able to keep all your files :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend adding an extra check to your condition. When you scroll a single-time, you update your component-state multiple times after a certain range (100), which is unnecessary. You only need to update it once.

It will keep updating because you meet the condition inside `handleScroll`, even though the background has already changed. The sheer amount of updates can cause your app to crash.

Try something like this it will update your component-state as expected and only when necessary: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-architecture-jepyc

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      navBckgroundColor: `blue`,
      altered: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }

  //use arrow function instead so that its "this" keyword points to the component's execution context. Otherwise, "this" will point to the global window object where you cannot use this.setState.
  handleScroll = e => {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100 && !this.state.altered) {
      this.setState({
        navBckgroundColor: `red`,
        altered: true
      });
    } else if(window.pageYOffset < 100 && this.state.altered) {
      this.setState({
        navBckgroundColor: `blue`,
        altered: false
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar bckGroundColor={this.state.navBckgroundColor} />
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
handleScroll = e => {
    console.log(e.target.scrollTop);
    if (window.scrollY > 100) {
      this.setState({
        navBckgroundColor: `red`
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        navBckgroundColor: `blue`
      });
    }
  }
```

Please see the workable code on :

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-swirles-bwl06
```

also your window.screenX will always output the same value, and thus no change to the colors.

I have changed that in the code as well

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.scrollY` instead of `window.screenY` and also bind the handleScroll method.

```
handleScroll = (e) => {
    if (window.scrollY > 100) {
      this.setState({
        navBckgroundColor: `red`
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        navBckgroundColor: `blue`
      });
    }
  }
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-feather-l567w)